# What are some good resources for Javascript Error handling

Tags: javascript

I recently ran into some issues this week on a web app that I built and I realized that I didn't have a good process in place for handling errors. What are some good resources on the subject? I'm talking links, books, videos, slides, whatever.

Comment: For catching errors there are [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) for the code and [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/) for the JSON data. This code snippet can help you get some errors too.

Comment: I use JSHint for all of my code. I'm concerned with overall methodology and techniques that can use when architecting your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This are a some of good articles:

- [The art of throwing JavaScript errors](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/03/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors/)
- [A chapter from Eloquent JavaScript Book](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter5.html)